# Where to get the latest update for TFS 2012?

Tags: updates

I make a google for this and it results as this blog site from msdn and about update 1 for Team Foudnation Server 2012.

I'm not sure if it is the latest update for TFS 2012.

How can we get it for sure officially from  Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38185) the droid, i.e. Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 with Update 4, you are looking for?

Comment: It is what I'm looking for. Thank you! And indeed I want to know how can we recieve news on such update when they are available to download?